# Cannot convert ‘gpio**’ to ‘gpio*’ for argument ‘1’

Tags: c++, pointers

I have an

> cannot convert ‘gpio**’ to ‘gpio*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void timer_hard(gpio*)’

error for this test code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct gpio{
  short const pin;
  short must;
  short flag;
}handle_out{0,0,0},handle_in{1,0,0},lock{2,0,0},mouth{3,0,0},ring_hard{4,0,0},ring_soft{5,0,0};

gpio *gpio_0[]={&handle_out,&handle_in,&lock,&mouth};

void timer_hard(gpio *array){
  std::cout << sizeof(gpio_0) << '\n';
  std::cout << sizeof(array) << '\n';
  for (int i = 0; i<sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);i++){
    std::cout << array[i].pin << '\n';
  };
  std::cout << '\n';
  for (int i = 0; i<sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);i++){
    std::cout << array[i].flag << '\n';
  };
  lock.flag = 1;
  std::cout << '\n';
  for (int i = 0; i<sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);i++){
    std::cout << array[i].flag << '\n';
  };
}

main(){
  timer_hard(gpio_0);
}
```

Please, tell me what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Main should have a return type in C++ (`int`).

Comment: Fyi, `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])` is certainly not what you think,  and with as much certainty, wrong, considering `gpio *array` is a function parameter. Your actual error is because `gpio_0` converts to a pointer to first element, which is also a pointer. Thus, a pointer to pointer to struct, passed to a function expecting a pointer to struct.

Comment: The error is pretty clear; The array `gpio *gpio_0[]` has decayed to a pointer, so it is of type `gpio**`. Change the parameter declaration and the method to reflect this.

Comment: Make the function to take array size `void timer_hard(gpio **array, int gposize)` and use `gposize` instead of `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])`. Of course you will have to use -> as in `array[i]->pin` etc

Comment: Or make a template requiring a reference to sized array, where the size is a non-type template argument deduced from the call site.

Comment: Consider: https://tio.run/##vZLLboMwEEX3fMVIlYhJaJT0sQkkn8AqO4qQBQasgo2MqZRafDvFdh5EUVeVKhbY19czlzNkbftcZtk4PlGW1X1OIKS8k4Lg5uA406LPJJQt5coB6CouJGScdRJayoKr1PSdvO2KGpeBM1SY5TVJeS/Vxp@ewT8rlKmtFWqefaoXu24mY6Ve7UZQVqYVFrl6mwkdL6R6N0LgOJI0bY3llLhnHS0ZySE6zCOnghQpFgKfQKcHI8ISuUbz4igJrvLMi642bfFgB0ZH2AM13Oq4wFsisOQC4gQQZRKod4ajQBDZCwZLczWmSQD2ake/SSrNC9CDPdI2/W02ggm2iZO9cm8wffeK0Xc1QN816O6RyFNLGG4IHH2Y4/niNAdJGyIMXnSEGQ7PDFnmu102VYQwNDl5gWwQTyuLD7YIfrHZQnPXPdowOkB5hmms2lJMAC092MMmABpay1oXRV5AVyvPju@uZXkhu57@xHnL4SHd5eTPnfSP/dBKj8Ce7GH7r70Hx2kwZchcnM30PK3JMI4/

Answer (score 0):

`gpio *gpio_0[]` is an two dimensional array, what means it's of type `gpio **`.